# Non-sequitur in Tower Heist, "We're on for Thanksgiving"

Tags: tower-heist

In Tower Heist (2011), about halfway through the FBI agent calls Josh and tells him that the court date is moved up to Thanksgiving. He then turns to the crew and says, "It worked, we're on for Thanksgiving." What worked? It seems like some critical part of the plot of has been edited out, or did I miss something?

Answer (score 1):

You may recall the scene where Denham walks into Shaw's apartment and Shaw's attorney tells her the court date has been moved to Thanksgiving by the judge's secretary.  As we see later in the movie, the judge isn't even in the same state on Thursday, which means the judge's secretary lied, or someone called Shaw's office *pretending* to be the judge's secretary.  Considering they all knew rather high level people in NYC, and the fact that one of the employees (Miss Iovenko) was set to take her bar exam, it's logical to believe Iovenko made the call and changed the court date with Shaw's attorney.  Whomever made the call is inconsequential, it's just clear from the empty courthouse that the FBI was misled.

That would explain about them "taking the bait", because Shaw and company were going to clear the apartment which would allow Josh's crew to break into the penthouse.